# Get value of form element inserted with DOM manipulation, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a solution to get values of input checkboxes, which are inserted using .html() inside a form, using jQuery.

I am not looking for $('#form').serialize(); solution, which doesn't work in this case.

Here is how checkboxes be created

```
$.each(ds.result, function(k,user) {
    rows += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="sel'+user['id']+'"></td><td><button onclick="edituser(\''+user['id']+'\',\''+user['fullname']+'\',\''+user['gender']+'\',\''+user['birthyear']+'\',\''+user['location']+'\',\''+user['email']+'\',\''+user['phone']+'\');">Edit</button></td><td>'+user['fullname']+'</td><td>'+user['gender']+'</td><td>'+user['birthyear']+'</td><td>'+user['location']+'</td><td>'+user['xtimelogin']+'</td></tr>';
});
$('#filter-users-tbody').html(rows);
```

And my form

```
<form method="post" id="form-select-users">
<tbody id="filter-users-tbody"></tbody>
</form>
```

And what I tried so far

```
function getusers() {
    alert('here');
    console.log($("#form-select-users").serialize());
    console.log($("#form-select-users > input").val());
    // $("#form-select-users").submit();
};
```

None of them work

Maybe I miss some small thing, but it took me much time anyways.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The HTML is invalid, and consequently the checkboxes may not be in the form when the browser is done with handling it. You can't have a `tbody` as a direct child of a `form`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder let me try with proper way, as form will cover entire html

Comment: @T.J.Crowder okay, now serialize works! thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML is invalid, you can't have a `tbody` as a direct child of a `form`. So the checkboxes probably aren't in the form by the time the browser has sorted it out. Move the `form` to be around the *entire* table.

Example of the problem:

```js
var ds = {
    result: [
        {id: 1, fullname: "One"},
        {id: 2, fullname: "Two"},
        {id: 3, fullname: "Three"}
    ]
};
var rows = "";
$.each(ds.result, function(k,user) {
    rows += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="sel'+user['id']+'"></td><td><button onclick="edituser(\''+user['id']+'\',\''+user['fullname']+'\',\''+user['gender']+'\',\''+user['birthyear']+'\',\''+user['location']+'\',\''+user['email']+'\',\''+user['phone']+'\');">Edit</button></td><td>'+user['fullname']+'</td><td>...</td></tr>';
});
$('#filter-users-tbody').html(rows);
$("input[type=button]").on("click", getusers);
function getusers() {
    console.log($("#form-select-users").serialize());
}
```

```html
<table>
<form method="post" id="form-select-users">
<tbody id="filter-users-tbody"></tbody>
</form>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click me after ticking some boxes">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example of the solution:

```js
var ds = {
    result: [
        {id: 1, fullname: "One"},
        {id: 2, fullname: "Two"},
        {id: 3, fullname: "Three"}
    ]
};
var rows = "";
$.each(ds.result, function(k,user) {
    rows += '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="sel'+user['id']+'"></td><td><button onclick="edituser(\''+user['id']+'\',\''+user['fullname']+'\',\''+user['gender']+'\',\''+user['birthyear']+'\',\''+user['location']+'\',\''+user['email']+'\',\''+user['phone']+'\');">Edit</button></td><td>'+user['fullname']+'</td><td>...</td></tr>';
});
$('#filter-users-tbody').html(rows);
$("input[type=button]").on("click", getusers);
function getusers() {
    console.log($("#form-select-users").serialize());
    // $("#form-select-users").submit();
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form-select-users">
<table>
<tbody id="filter-users-tbody"></tbody>
</table>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Click me after ticking some boxes">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in your code.

1: When you add `tbody` tag without a `table` tag, `tbody` tag is not created.

2: Remove `>` from the following statement `console.log($("#form-select-users input").val());`.
`>` looks for immediate child and `input is not an immediate child.